# Свойства и методы в ООП на PHP

Tags: ооп, php

```
class MyClass
{
    private $a;
    private $b;

    private function getNumA()
    {
        $this->a = 500;
    }

    // Вариант №1
    private function getNumB()
    {
        $this->b = $this->a + 100;
    }

    // Вариант №2
    private function getNumB($a)
    {
        $this->b = $a + 100;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->getNumA();

        // Вариант №1
        $this->getNumB();

        // Вариант №2
        $this->getNumB($this->a);
    }
}
```

Оба варианта использования свойства и методов работают.

**Вопрос:** какой вариант правильный и почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

чисто идеалогически неправильные оба варианта в связи с дурацким именованием методов класса, метод называется **get**NumA, соответственно не понятно почему вместо **return $this->a** мы видим инициализацию поля класса...

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Всегда и везде, любые методы название которых начинается с  **get**,  должны быть публичными, к тому-же, подразумевается что эти методы используются для получения какого либо значения, соответственно они обязательно должны что-либо возвращать. Например:

```
class User {
    private $_name;

    public function __construct($name = false) {
        if($name) {
           $this->_name = $name;
        }
    }
    public function getName(){
        return !empty($this->_name) ? $this->_name : 'Гость';
    }
}

$user = new User('Василий');
$guestUser = new User();
echo $user->getName(); // -> Василий
echo $guestUser->getName(); // -> Гость
```

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Ну и теперь уже можно о непосредственно программировании.

естественно передавать поля класса методам того-же класса в том-же классе :) - глупо и максимум к чему приведет так это к неразберихе.

Правда, хотел бы отметить, что, иногда, в этом есть смысл, например у нашего класса есть публичный метод который, естественно, может принимать какие-то параметры "извне", тогда, конечно-же - правильным( читай рабочим :) ) - будет второй вариант.

PS: хотел бы добавить что по хорошему private поля принято именовать начиная с символа нижнего подчеркивания, т.е. не **$a**, а **$_a**, тоже самое можно сказать о приватных методах.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, использовать параметры в private и protected методах не желательно? Можно и нужно использовать свойства класса.

PS: Со стилем кодирования Zend знаком.

Comment: Если мы говорим о конкретном примере - безусловно да, в общем случае - безусловно можно и нужно. Во первых так у нас хранится состояние, во вторых мы всегда можем расширить код, вот допустим в примере класса приведенного мною мы могли бы, например, дергать перевод слова гость из какого либа хранилища данных по значению языка, при этом нам бы не пришлось переписывать код вызова. А пример с return 
**$this->name ? $this->_name : 'Гость'** я написал для примера, но уже тут видна суть - по факту $_name возвращается не всегда :) При этом вы можете использовать этот метод не задумываясь.

Comment: Более того - вам не важно как это имя получается, вам достаточно знать что метод **getName()** так или иначе вернет имя конкретного пользователя, как он это делает - абсолютно "его проблемы" :)

Comment: Если присваивать значение $_name мы будем в одном из методов класса. Допустимо использовать вызов этого метода в конструкторе?

Comment: Задача конструктора - инициализировать объект так, чтобы сущность было завершенной и с ней можно было работать, как видите в данном примере - это изменение не нарушило-бы этого правила. 

К тому-же мы как и прежде имеем возможность как-то изменять поле $_name не переписывая код вне класса. Таким образом - да, можно.

Но в таких ситуациях нужно думать - как сделать код читабельнее. И тут уже, как понимаете, единого правила нет и быть не может.

Answer (score 2):

Нет смысла передавать в метод переменную, которую вы используете из того же класса (если вы, конечно, в будущем не подразумеваете изменение данной логики). Это вводит только неразбериху в код, так как в будущем вы возможно забудете, что это за аргумент и несомненно будет соблазн передать что угодно другое, нежели закрытое значение данного класса. Судя по текущей цели кода, это будет ошибкой.